# Regex: Select only the line 3 (mark particular line)

Tags: regex, notepad++

Suppose I want to select only line 3, to replace it with another one in many documents.

I use regex from Notepad++ and GrepWin. I have tried something like

```
\A^(.*){2}.*$
```

but it is not working.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564913/regex-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: one single attempt

Comment: What programming language are you using? What pattern have you tried? As it stands right now, there isn't enough information available to answer your question. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I use regex from Notepad++ and GrepWin. I have try something like \A^(.*){2}.*$  but is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\A((?:.*\R){2}).*((?s:.*))\z
```

Replace with `$1my new line$2`.

Details:

- `\A` - start of document
- `((?:.*\R){2})` - Group 1 (created with the pair of unescaped parentheses) apturing 2 sequences of zero or more chars other than a newline followed with a linebreak (two first lines)
- `.*` - zero ore more chars other than newline (this will get replaced)
- `((?s:.*))` - Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars up to the....
- `\z` - end of the document.

The `$1` is a backreference to the value captured with the parenthetical part of the regex.

Comment: hello Wiktor. Your regex is good, but it doesn't select only one time the line number 3. It selects all multiple of 3 line....6,9,12.. line. 

So if I want to REPLACE ALL, will replace more then strictly the line 3.

Comment: Ah yes. You need to add one more group. See the update.

Comment: Works. Thanks you very much